# Zilog z80 I, R registers purpose

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, z80, micro-architecture

There are I and R registers in the Control section of the Z80 cpu, what is their purpose and usage?

[image: a picture from documentation]

Answer (score 7):

The R register is the memory refresh register. It's used to refresh dynamic RAM. Essentially, it is incremented on each instruction and placed on the address bus (when not in use for fetching or storing data) so that dynamic RAM chips can be refreshed.

You can ignore the R register, although people did use it as a source of semi random numbers.

The I register is the interrupt vector base register. In interrupt mode 2, the Z80 has a table of 128 interrupt vectors. The I register tells you the page in RAM where that table is.

Comment: (ZX Spectrum details, maybe other platforms differ slightly): the `R` register fills up low 8 bits of interrupt vector, i.e. when IM2 interrupt is request, the word from address `IR` is fetched and used as interrupt handler. The table is then 256 vectors long (but only 257 bytes long). This makes positioning of interrupt handler a bit limited, as it must start on some kind of "0xABAB" address, where low 8 bits are equal to high 8 bits, so the whole 257 bytes of table are filled with the same 0xAB value.

Comment: @Ped7g, your information is incorrect. The Z80 manual says "The IM 2 instruction sets the vectored interrupt mode 2. This mode allows an indirect call to any memory location by an 8-bit vector supplied from the peripheral device. This vector then becomes the least-significant eight bits of the indirect pointer, while the I register in the CPU provides the most significant eight bits". Some peripheral devices for ZX Spectrum did not provide the lower 8 bits properly, hence the need to use 257 bytes table. It has nothing to do with the register R.

Comment: @AlekseyPichugin I don't care what the manual says, I'm writing how the ZX Spectrum computer operates. The ordinary IM2 mode with the bare ZX Spectrum (no peripheral) does use the value in `R` as low 8 bits of the handler address. It's probably because the content of `R` is on the address bus and nothing overwrites it with more meaningful value when the IRQ happens.

Comment: @AlekseyPichugin I may be actually wrong, thinking about it... What I know for sure, that *all* of the 257 byte table is used, and also on odd/even addresses, so you need target address to consist of two same 8 bit values, but whether the source of random low 8 bits is `R` directly, or just junk on the bus in the time of IRQ, I don't know. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Ped7g in `IM2` the Z80 picks up an index  up from the *data* bus which is put there by the interrupting device. This is concatenated with the `I` register value to give a 16 bit address. Generally speaking, the `R` register is not involved. For the Spectrum, it could be that `IM2` was not supported by the external devices and if you used it, you would pick up garbage from the data bus. I do know that the ULA didn't decode addresses properly for IO operations so it is entirely plausible that it would mirror the R register on the data bus.

Comment: It is definitely the case that the Spectrum has no hardware to load the bus during an interrupt cycle; traditional advice was to put your interrupt handler at an address that is a palindrome and fill up the previously mentioned 257-byte table. Since R is a seven-bit counter, wouldn't this behaviour imply you needed to spend only 129 bytes? @Ped7g as an emulator author besides anything else, do you have a reference for the behaviour?

Comment: @Tommy nope... I was just doing demos for ZX, I didn't bother with complete HW accuracy, as long as it did work without a hitch, it was good enough for me.

Comment: Oh, well, off topic then probably, but if we're talking unintended uses of I and R, then the ZX80/81 is probably more interesting: the Z80 loads I onto the top part of the bus during the refresh cycle, presumably for no reason beyond convenience; the ZX80/81 use the refresh cycle to fetch video and because it's there I is the top part of the video fetch address. Though R isn't part of the address, it is used to count video columns. Neither is an intended purpose or usage of the Z80, but are real-life usages in a particular[ly inventive] system.